# Servlet Filters - Problems with manipulating JSP response data

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm building a web application which is supposed to measure httprequests/response times as well as response size. for this task I used: http://angelborroy.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/dump-request-and-response-using-javaxservletfilter/ filter, which does everything I need only it dumps requests/response data instead of print the response size.
It works just fine with Servlets, but there just seems to be a problem with JSPs... when I'm trying to load up a JSP in the browser, it displays a blank page, and the filter echos that the response size is 0.

Again, it works flawlessly when the requested page is a servlet... any idea what can cause this issue?

**UPDATE:** I've been trying to find any filter which wraps a servlet response and then able to forward the response back to the client (even as is!) but without any luck, if anyone can point me out to a working example, it doesn't matter what the wrapper does, just a simple wrapper which does something on the response content and forwards it back to the client after the change, i'll more than grateful.

P.S

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flush the writer and the stream after `doFilter()`:

```
filterChain.doFilter(req, wrappedResp);
pw.getWriter().flush();
pw.getStream().flush();
```

Please note that the linked codes does not throw `IllegalStateException` when:

- you call [`getOutputStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and the `getWriter` method has been called on this response

or

- you call [`getWriter()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) and the `getOutputStream` method has already been called for this response object.

Check the source code of [javamelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) too. Their codes looks more robust.

---

The [PrintWriter uses an inner BufferedReader](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/io/PrintWriter.java.html#131) and it needs a flush. It was just a quick solution so maybe the `getStream().flush()` isn't really required. Please notice that I called `pw.get*().flush()`, not `response.get*().flush()`. But it's still just a quick answer for the specific problem when JSPs are not showed. If you need a production grade solution check the source of javamelody. They probably handle a lot more corner cases (like the mentioned `IllegalStateException`) than the referred article.
 I would start with the source of javamelody and I'd cut out the unnecessary features.

Comment: It works!!! thanks a lot, can you please explain in a few words why did the flush()ing do the trick?

Comment: And also, if you're saying that getOutputStream() should throw an "IllegalStateException" when getWriter() was already called, I can't call "flush" on both, can I?